# Simple conversion of the 1D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

i have a huge dataset as array in the format below

```
 #input array
    array([ 5.94911 , -1.0366  ,  3.25678 ])
```

i need to convert it to arrays in the format below.

```
array([[5.94911],
       [-1.0366],
       [ 3.25678]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
>>> a = array([ 5.94911 , -1.0366  ,  3.25678 ])
>>> np.vstack(a)
array([[ 5.94911],
       [-1.0366 ],
       [ 3.25678]])
>>>
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = array([ 5.94911 , -1.0366  ,  3.25678 ])
>>> np.array([[i] for i in a])
array([[ 5.94911],
       [-1.0366 ],
       [ 3.25678]])
>>>
```

But of course `vstack` is recommended.

Answer (score 4):

```py
a = array([ 5.94911 , -1.0366  ,  3.25678 ])
dataset = np.array(a).reshape(-1,1)
```

This solution will not use additional memory for reshaping.